# C++ getline pass file or cin

Tags: c++, iostream

I searched internet and read manuals for hours but I can't figure out this one:

My program gets one optional argument, which is file name. Consider this conditions

```
std::ifstream file;

if (argc > 1) {
    file.open(argv[1]);
}

if (file.is_open()) {
    processInput(file);
    file.close();
} else {
    processInput(std::cin);
}
```

in function `processInput` I'm trying to read all lines from input and do something with them like this:

```
void processInput(std::basic_istream<char> inputStream) {
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inputStream, line)) {
        processLine(line);
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error in basic_istream, so I don't have any clue what type should I pass to this function. I tried only blind shots.

Comment: _"I'm getting an error in `basic_istream`"_ - Please edit your post and include the _exact_ error(s) you are getting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Streams are not copyable. You have to pass the stream by reference:

```
//                                         v-- here
void processInput(std::basic_istream<char> &inputStream) {
```

By the way, there's a shorter way to write `std::basic_istream<char>`, which is

```
void processInput(std::istream &inputStream) {
```